# Is there a way to send game invites?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I was wondering if it was possible for a bot to either forward or create game invites to games like cod, rainbow six siege, etc. When I try to make my bot forward a game invite it just says cannot send an empty message.

It's not much but this is what I tried doing to forward the invites:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    await message.channel.send(message.content)
```

of course, it isn't finished and eventually I will have to make sure it only forwards invites, but for now I'd just like to know if it is even possible to forward game invites and how exactly i can do that.

Comment: As far as I know, that is not something discord.py supports, probably because game invites are handled by discord game SDK, not the bot API.